# APK - screen support

Tags: android, apk

I have an APK for test and I wonder if is possible to know what screen it supports before upload to Google Play.
I don't have access to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Regards,
Claudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract your APK file and you'll get the Manifest file.

Right click APK file, Select Extract files

Use software like winrar, 7zip

Answer (score 2):

You can open the .apk file with something like WinRAR and view the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Open the apk using WinRar or 7Zip and look for the AndroidManifest.xml